# Read binary data image JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So I am using mongoDB as my database and I have saved an image in mongoDB in binary format.

The image below is how the data is being displayed in my database.

[image]

I have tried the following:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64{<%= user.img.data %>}"/>
```

But the above code does not seem to work. Please note I am using EJS as a tempting engine.

After doing the inspect element on google chrome I found that the data was being shown like so:

[image]

**I am not sure how to read this binary image and display it in a img tag in html.**

**UPDATE:**

After making the changes recommended by Alex Matos in the comments I get the following output:

[image]

Comment: You are missing a comma after base64 so it should read as: <img src="data:image/bmp;base64,{<%= user.img.data %>}"/>

Comment: I think you must return your buffer like a string. Something like this `var buf2 = new Buffer(user.img.data).toString('base64');
console.log(buf2.toString());` I suppose that you uses nodejs

Comment: @Kush thank you for the comment. I tried your suggestion but it did not work.

Comment: @AlexMatos Im gonna try your suggestion now. And yes I'm using node.js

Comment: Ok, Let me know if it work it.

Comment: @AlexMatos please see updated question. I still can't get the image to display. Now I am wondering whether I actually saved the image in mongoDB the right way. I am not sure about that.

Comment: I saw your update, but I'm not sure that your syntax will be right because the key at the beginning and the end is not a good clue. See this img in base_64 `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG....` You forgot a colon as well. The return code look like a buffer in HEX

Answer (score 1):

If you really got the images data and saved it i mongo db, you could render the image in a canvas and append it wherever you need.

```
// Renders the image data in a canvas off screen
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var data = ctx.putImageData(YOUR_MONGODB_DATA,0,0);

// Initializes a new image from canvas and appends it to the parent you want
var image = new Image();
image.id = "rendered-picture"
image.src = canvas.toDataURL();
document.getElementById('PARENT_ID').appendChild(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try returning data from your server using [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php).

For example:

```
    <?php
        $picture = base64_encode(user.img.data);
       <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64{<%= picture %>}"/>
    ?>
```